# combining multiple mysql_num_rows queries by using count in a single table

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to combine the following queries (Can we combine these queries by using COUNT or another way).

```
$resultacgc = mysql_query("SELECT mno FROM table1 WHERE (m_jid='$sid' AND decision='accept-gf')");
  $numacgc = mysql_num_rows($resultacgc);
$resultacp = mysql_query("SELECT mno FROM table1 WHERE (m_jid='$sid' AND decision='accept-p')");
  $numacp = mysql_num_rows($resultacp);
$resultacpc = mysql_query("SELECT mno FROM table1 WHERE (m_jid='$sid' AND decision='accept-pc')");
  $numacpc = mysql_num_rows($resultacpc);
$resultacr = mysql_query("SELECT mno FROM table1 WHERE (m_jid='$sid' AND decision='accept-rdy')");
  $numacr = mysql_num_rows($resultacr);
$resultacft = mysql_query("SELECT mno FROM table1 WHERE (m_jid='$sid' AND decision='accept-ft')");
  $numacft = mysql_num_rows($resultacft);
```

P.S.:I know "mysql_*" is deprecated.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mysql IN.

Like so:

```
"SELECT mno FROM table1 WHERE (m_jid='$sid' AND decision IN ('accept-gf', '...', '...'))"
```

In case you want to get each count you would need to do something like this:

```
"SELECT decision, COUNT(*) AS count FROM table1 WHERE (m_jid='$sid' AND decision IN ('accept-gf', '...', '...')) GROUP BY decision"
```

Comment: Do you mean: $counts=mysql_query("SELECT mno FROM table1 WHERE (m_jid='$sid' AND decision IN ('accept-gf', '...', '...'))");

Comment: The first example delivers all rows you can use the mysql_num_rows on